# Adding intPtr to int generate error on .net framework 3.5

Tags: c#, unmanaged, unsafe

i have this code:

```
lvItem.pszText = (IntPtr)(lpRemoteBuffer + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LV_ITEM)));
```

it works fine on 4.0.

if i downgrade the project to 3.5 it gives me this error :

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.IntPtr' and 'int'
```

any idea how do i fix that to make it work on 3.5

and i dont know why it works in 4.0 ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup - if you look at [the documentation for the Addition property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.op_addition.aspx) you'll see that operator was only introduced in .NET 4. You shouldn't need the cast, by the way.

On .NET 3.5 you could probably use:

```
lvItem.pszText = new IntPtr(lpRemoteBuffer.ToInt64() +
                            Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LV_ITEM)));
```

Of course you then need to hope you're not on a 32-bit system with a pointer which goes over `int.MaxValue` :)

Comment: im developing on 64bit and it works great on .net framework 4

Answer (score 0):

IntPtr didn't support pointer arithmetic prior to .NET 4.0. If you want to work that way with pointers, you have to use real pointers insteat of IntPtr.